# Get a message's content from their id

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Is there a way to get a message's content from its id? If so, how can I do that? I've read through its documentation but I found nothing.

In the documentation, it says you can get a `discord.Message`'s ID by using `.id`, but I don't have the `discord.Message` object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the channel id but only the message id, you just need to loop through your accessible channels and check which one(s)* have the message that matches your id.

```
from discord import NotFound


for channel in client.get_all_channels():
    try:
        msg = await channel.get_message(id)
    except NotFound:
        continue
    print(msg.content)

# where `id` is the message id and `client` is the bot or user
```

<sub>* Message id isn't unique to the system, that is why the only way is to loop through all available channels, since message id is only unique to the channel. It is possible (quite unlikely though) to match two distinct messages with the same id from two different channels.</sub>

Comment: `get_message` has now been renamed to [`fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)

Answer (score 0):

In the rewrite branch of discord.py you can use the `get_message()` coroutine (documentation found [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.get_message)) to find a message using its ID. I'm not sure if there's a way to do it in 0.16.12

Comment: [`get_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_message) exists in 0.16.x, but it needs the channel id too.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't see it when I went through the documentation. Thanks for the info