# How to get message by id discord.py

Tags: python, url-rewriting, discord.py, message

I'm wondering how to get a message by its message id. I have tried `discord.fetch_message(id)` and `discord.get_message(id)`, but both raise:

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'fetch_message'/'get_message'
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419190, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message. Think the syntax is `channel.fetch_message(id)`

Comment: could you do guild.fetch_message(id) ?

Comment: ok, one more question, how would you get the current channel they're sending the command in ?

Comment: ooh ok, i sent that after I saw your next reply, sorry about that

Comment: guild = ctx.guild
channel = guild.channels
message = await channel.fetch_message(int(id)) raises: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When getting a message, you're going to need an `abc.Messageable` object - essentially an object where you can send a message in, for example a text channel, a DM etc.

## Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def getmsg(ctx, msgID: int): # yes, you can do msg: discord.Message
                                   # but for the purposes of this, i'm using an int

    msg = await ctx.fetch_message(msgID) # you now have the message object from the id
                                         # ctx.fetch_message gets it from the channel
                                         # the command was executed in


###################################################

@bot.command()
async def getmsg(ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel, member: discord.Member):
    msg = discord.utils.get(await channel.history(limit=100).flatten(), author=member)
    # this gets the most recent message from a specified member in the past 100 messages
    # in a certain text channel - just an idea of how to use its versatility
```

---

**References:**

- [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable)
- [`TextChannel.history()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.history)
- [`TextChannel.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)
- [`Context.fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.fetch_message)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Good luck with the bot :)

Comment: Thanks ive been working on it, and its funny that I don't know that but I have a full on currency system with mongodb, lmao.

Comment: Haha, everything comes with time. Soon you won't even need the docs for anything and the code will be flowing from your fingers like there's no tomorrow!

Comment: Haha, yeah, hopefully. 
Do you have a discord? mine is @ɦօռɛʏքօօք#0099 if you want to add me.

Comment: Sent a friend request!